# Retag [backupexec] to [backup-exec]?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

On Server Fault, there are 56 tags [backupexec] and no [backup-exec] tags.

This seems odd to me, as you would say it as Backup Exec (2 words), much like you would say Windows Server 2008 R2 as multiple words (which has the tag [windows-server-2008-r2]).

Splitting this up would also allow for different versions of the software to be discussed, i.e [backup-exec-11d], [backup-exec-12.5], [backup-exec-2010] and would make it easier to distinguish what the poster was talking about, as they don't always state.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

If these are not split you can still easily do [backupexec-11d], [backupexec-12.5], or [backupexec-2010] to identify a particular version.

I am hesitant to start retagging anything when there seems to be no confusion and everyone is using the current tag.

Your example of [windows-server] really isn't that great, because windows also comes in desktop variations and so on.

It might also be somewhat confusing in light of the other [backup-*] tags like below.  These tags do not identify a particular product and instead are about specific facets of backup.

- backup-restoration× 82
- backup-server× 2
- backup-solution× 2
- backup-strategies× 4

Comment: You say there's no confusion with the current tag, which is true - but probably because everyone has gone with the suggested backupexc. I know I've gone to add a backup exec tag before, and just used backupexec because that's what it suggested, even though I disagree. If the system suggested backup-exec, that's what I'd use.

Comment: I agree with this. The goal of tags is categorization, and if there's no confusion between tags, then we should let it slide until [tag synonyms](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2779/could-the-tagging-system-be-enhanced-to-support-tag-synonyms) are implemented -- at that point, we can display whatever we want, even if the users input the old tag. @Ben

Comment: As @Ben said, we tend to follow rather than create a new tag, but that doesn't mean it is the best way of doing it. If things can be improved, why not do it?